# Selenium "StoreText" to use in other field

Tags: testing, selenium

Please help,

I want to use the value that i stored using storeText.

My problem is, how do i use this on the other fields of the page?

Thanks in advance!

For example:

I want to get the name of this customer, and verify it on another site if its existing by entering the name on the search field on another site?

Answer (score 3):

See the *"Variable substitution"* paragraph of [the documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storedVars), it even has a nice example of usage for storing a name from multiple fields:

> ### Variable substitution
>
> Variable substitution provides a simple way to include a previously
>   stored variable in a command parameter. This is a simple mechanism, by
>   which the variable to substitute is indicated by `${variableName}`.
>   Multiple variables can be substituted, and intermixed with static
>   text.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> store       | Mr                   | title
> storeValue  | nameField            | surname
> store       | ${title} ${surname}  | fullname
> type        | textElement          | Full name is: ${fullname}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get the text from the webelement store it in a global static variable and call the variable in the other test case?